# Возможно ли на одном VDS поднять openVPN и веб сервер?

Tags: openvpn, vds

Новичок, не очень разбираюсь в администрировании серверов, технически такое возможно реализовать? Есть сервер, сейчас использую как VPN, но хотелось бы там еще и пару сайтиков разместить с поддержкой php/mysql, такое возможно?

Comment: Да, вполне возможно. Вы пробовали? Столкнулись с чем-то непонятным?

Comment: нет, просто не знаю, нормально ли это

Comment: Но спросили вы совсем не это.